# What are some advanced background topics I'll need for distributed systems and networks research?

Tags: reference-request, distributed-systems, computer-networks, security, research

I am a new graduate student in Computer Science who would like to be able to read and understand modern and new **distributed systems** research papers. My current background / courses and understanding is in the level of undergraduate and beginner graduate level courses in:

- Networks (TCP/IP stack and applications)
- Distributed Systems (Graduate level course with Time (logical/vector clocks), 2PC and 3PC, Multicast and membership, election, Consistency , Consensus and Quorums (Paxos), DHTs and Overlays and some modern applications like ZooKeeper etc)
- Undergraduate Algorithms, Discrete Mathematics and Theory of Computation (basic DFA/NFA and intro to Turing Machines with no rigorous mathematics)

However, I find this background insufficient to read modern research in networks and distributed systems and in particular, I am not aware of modern protocols like QUIC and the formal methods mentioned in the papers which I believe include some sort of model checking and the likes. Also many of the topics I have mentioned above in distributed systems - I lack the background to verify and prove correctness of these protocols and even follow the proofs that they have given.

Any suggestions on a **reading list** that can prepare me to be in a position to **understand modern research** in this area would be very helpful.